# c++ kinect & openni: convert depth to real world

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I need to convert depth information aquired with a kinect sensor, 
to real world 3D coordinates.

I know that the way to do this is by using a `DepthGenerator`
and call `ConvertProjectiveToRealWorld`
but this requires the sensor to be connected....

Does anyone knows a way to do it without the sensor connected?

Comment: What is the reason you cannot simply connect the sensor?  How can you expect to test any software you write without the sensor?

Comment: i have some data already recorded that need to be processed...
it would be very helpfull if i could do it at home where i can't take the sensor with me...

Answer (score 1):

How is your depth information stored?

The easiest way would probably be initializing OpenNI from a depth recording (.oni file). You can create .oni files using the NiViewer sample bundled with OpenNI (press on '?' to see the list of commands, one of them should let you record).

If your data isn't stored in an oni file, you should be able to create a dummy file with a single depth frame in it. That should be enough to cause the sensor parameters to be stored in the oni file as well - the parameters that are used in the projective to real world conversion.